# Sound not working in ASUS Zenbook OLED

Tags: sound, asus

this is the first time I write something in a forum of this kind, so I apologize if I do something that is not correct.

A few months ago, I bought an ASUS Zenbook 14 OLED laptop and in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, the sound of the internal speakers doesn't work (headphones and Bluetooth do work). The computer is set up with dual-boot with Windows (the audio works correctly in Windows 11).

I have seen other discussions about this, but I haven't been able to fix it with any of them.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, I finally found the solution. Really thanks to farfaa!. Here the url:
[asus_zenbook_UM3402YA](https://github.com/farfaaa/asus_zenbook_UM3402YA)

Answer (score 2):

I have also a ZenBook 14 OLED (UX5401z). With ubuntu 23.04 lunar and 6.2.0-20-generic kernel everything is ok. Only Fn + F10 for camera on/off don't work.
Upgrade your ubuntu and install asus linux toucpad from https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-numberpad-driver

Installation instructions based on [README](https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-numberpad-driver):

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-numberpad-driver
cd asus-numberpad-driver
sudo bash ./install.sh --user
```

Comment: Does Camera work otherwise, e.g. with the application Cheese, or on video calls?

Comment: Yes its works.... (In Vivaldi, skype, viber, etc)

Comment: Thanks, I need ubuntu 20.04 for compatibility with ROS Noetic (software for my work).